# How to put AppBarLayout with collapseMode overlay content layout?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have put AppBarLayout with `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` overlay by content `FrameLayout`. But when I'm scrolling in fragment AppBarLayout doesn't collapse.

How to make AppBarLayout collapsable and overling of the FrameLayout?

Here is my current page, but toolbar is not collapse,but I need to overlay and collapse it:
[image]

Here is my current xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/coordinator"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                        app:elevation="0dp"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">



                            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                                style="?android:attr/toolbarStyle"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                app:elevation="0dp"
                                app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
                                tools:ignore="NewApi"/>

                    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code. Hope it will help you

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:background="@color/bg"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_30dp">

                <com.tncstories.stories.utils.CircularImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivProfile"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/scale_90dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/scale_90dp" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <com.tncstories.stories.widget.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:typeface="gotham_medium" />

            <com.tncstories.stories.widget.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvHoots"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:typeface="gotham_book" />

            <com.vanniktech.emoji.EmojiTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSmiley"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_10dp"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                app:emojiSize="25sp" />


            <com.tncstories.stories.widget.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMyFriends"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/red_rect_box"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/scale_10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/scale_15dp"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/scale_15dp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/scale_10dp"
                android:text="@string/my_friends"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <com.tncstories.stories.widget.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:typeface="bariol_bold" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2px"
            android:background="#eae6e6" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/red"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="10dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="10dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/light_grey" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2px"
            android:background="#eae6e6" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/mPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_10dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<!--<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView-->
<!--android:id="@+id/recyclerReading"-->
<!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
<!--android:layout_height="@dimen/scale_210dp"-->
<!--android:clipToPadding="false"-->
<!--android:paddingLeft="@dimen/scale_10dp" />-->

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: seems your `ViewPager` is below  `AppBarLayout` , but I need under

Comment: add this line to your toolbar  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"

Comment: use snap behind it

Comment: `snap`  - At the end of the scroll, if the view is only partially visible, it will be twisted to its nearest edge.... so it doesn't affect on overlay